# Trying to take average each time something is added

Tags: java

```
package gradeAvg;
import java.util.Scanner;
//Grade Average calculater
public class GradeAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter the first grade being added to the average:");
        double average = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("The average is now: " + average + " Please enter the second grade being averaged:");
        average += input.nextInt() ;
        System.out.print("The average is now: " + average + " Please enter the third grade being averaged:");
        average += input.nextInt() / 2;
        System.out.print("The average is now: " + average + " Please enter the fourth grade being averaged:");
        average += input.nextInt() / 2;
        System.out.print("The average is now: " + average + " Please enter the fifth grade being averaged:");
        average += input.nextInt() / 2;
        input.close();
        System.out.print(average);




    }

}
```

Hey guys, I'm really new to java, and pretty terrible at math, I'm supposed to be making a program that allows the user to input a value, have it averaged out, print it out, and then allow the input of another value, have it averaged, and print, and continue. Am i going wrong when I divide by 2 at the end of each input or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average is the sum of all the numbers divided by the number of numbers in the sum.

What you are doing here is not average. You are adding the half of every new number to the total sum. I don't what you are doing here.

Just to make things more understandable, let's make a `sum` and a `counter`:

```
public class GradeAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum;
        int counter;
        // ...
    }

}
```

Each time you ask for a number, you increment the counter and add the new number to `sum`:

```
int newNumber;
// ask for input
newNumber = input.nextInt()
sum += newNumber;
counter++;
```

You can then output the average like this:

```
System.out.println("The average is: " + (double)sum / counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong. each number you add weight 50% against the other numbers. 
you need to keep track of the count (number of elements) and the sum and each time divide the sum by the number of elements.
so each time you add a number the function should be:

> (OLD_AVERAGE*OLD_COUNT+NEW_NUMBER)/(OLD_COUNT+1)

or just use SUM and COUNT and each time AVERAGE=SUM/COUNT.
inc. count by 1 every new number. 
inc sum by the number entered.

Answer (score 0):

complete working solution... hope it helps...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 1;
    double average = 0;
    System.out.print("Please Enter the " + count + " grade being added to the average:");
    for (; count <= 5;) {
        sum = sum + input.nextInt();
        average = sum / count;
        System.out.println("The average is now: " + average);
        count++;
        if (count <= 5)
            System.out.println("Please enter the " + count + " grade being averaged:");
    }
    input.close();
}
```